# c++ unit testing with dependency and file writing

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I am a student and new for unit testing. I'm confused with testing problems when writing my project.

I have three functions `A()`, `B(string file)` and `C()`. `A()` is used for initialization and it creates a directory `temp` to store files. `B(string file)` writes file in `temp`. `C()` transfer the current files in `temp` to another place and mark these files. They are usually called in the following order:

```
         | - - - - - - - - - - - - -
        \ /                        |
A - - -> B (multiple times) - - -> C
```

(the three functions are kind of like the commands `init`, `add` and `commit` in the version control system *git*)

Here is the thing:

1. I've written the test and implementation of `A()`. In `testB()` I need the initialization, so I call `A()`. Though it is tested, it seems that it's a bad choice. What should I do? Should I just create the directory `temp` on my own in `testB()`?
2. If a file has been marked by `C()`, `B(string file)` should do nothing if  then we forward the file to `B(string file)`. How can I test this situation?

I'll aappreciate it if you can give detailed instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically every test environment provides something to initialize the test environment and shut this down after the test has run.

For example, [google test/gtest](https://github.com/google/googletest) provides `SetUp()` and `TearDown()` for every fixture. In this fixtures you can do all needed initialization and shutdown functionality you need for testing your DUT.

BTW: From my perspective it is absolutely acceptable to test all your 3 functions at once if they are related as they are. Even if some guys will call this then integration test, it is still doing what you want. It tests your code and check if it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks. You mean I can call `A()` in `Setup()`? And is it proper to access actual files in tests? It's said that it would be slow.

Comment: @seineo: Instead of say "Thangs" we have the Upvote button to "pay" :-) And if the answer fulfill your needs, accept it please. your question: If you need to access files for testing your functions, you have to do it. If the test takes longer, you may think about short files if it will decrease access time. But if the time is required to test, than it takes the time. You may decide to run some tests only on nightly builds.